# Intellij: Define default task to be used for all new Java projects

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

For almost every Java project I have, I define a new Gradle task to build a jar with the javadocs. Specifically, I add the following to almost every `build.gradle`:

```
task jarJavadoc(type: Jar, dependsOn: ['javadoc']) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives jarJavadoc
}
```

Is there a way to configure Intellij so that it automatically adds these lines to every new Gradle Java project?

Comment: You could develop a Gradle plugin which implements this functionality. Then, you would just need to apply that plugin in the respective Gradle build files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could explore couple of options:

- First is creating a gradle file (e.g. *init.gradle*) in your *GRADLE_HOME* directory (e.g *~/.gradle/*) and define the common parts there. Gradle always applies those files [first](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:configuring_projects_from_an_init_script) while processing your build scripts. Note, everything you configure there is going to be available in
  every Gradle project on your machine. Which means e.g. if you depend
  on Java plugin (like you do in an example you provided) and you create
  other project which doesn't depend on Java, this approach may produce
  configuration errors so use it with caution.
- You could write a simple Gradle plugin which adds common tasks you require to a project. With this approach you will still need to duplicate the `apply plugin: 'your plugin'`
- You could leverage [File and Code templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-code-templates.html) and update Gradle build script template to include the common code.
- You can also mix the last 2 examples and write a plugin which configures the common tasks and modify Gradle build script template to include your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the [nebula.javadoc-jar](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin#nebulajavadoc-jar) plugin.

Eg:

```
plugins {
    id 'nebula.javadoc-jar' version '5.1.0'
}
```